# Collect an input to list with Erlang

Tags: erlang

I need to create a program which reads number from console and collect them to list.
For example with input:

```
1
2
3
4
```

program should return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.
The algorithm is fairly simple:

- read input
- If input isnt empty push it to list
- else return result in list

I believe the program should look like this(# for parts which I don't know how to write):

```
read(L)->
  case io:fread("", "#what format")
    #number case ->
     read([N|L])
    #empty case ->
     lists:reverse(L)
  end.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you paste any code you've already created into the question?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19097507/2541573

Comment: The format specifiers for `io:fread` are listed here, along with some examples: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fread-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a recursive function like

```
-module(test).
-compile(export_all).

input(Acc) ->
    Data = io:get_line(""),
    Data2 = lists:sublist(Data, length(Data) - 1),
    case string:len(Data2) of
        0 ->
            Acc;
        _ ->
            input(Acc ++ [Data2])
    end.
```

which solves the problem:

```
rorra:~/erlang > erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:input([]).
hello
world

["hello","world"]
3>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you recommend a good article (or book) about erlang standard library? From my perspective the documentation is really strange(it's too descriptive and examples are silly)

Comment: @kharandziuk I don't really know any about standard io in Erlang, I read Amstrong book and Learn You Some Erlang for Great code, and then I continue my learning by teaching, I'm building erlang screencast but in spanish, and to do it I went though the different documentation for the modules and by checking the source code of the different erlang modules (its open source so you can check the documentation and code of the io module), other than that, random blogs acceded by google search